# Printing a map with Leaflet

Tags: jquery, google-maps, leaflet

I am trying to create a printable view containing only a map, created using Leaflet. I am creating the map using a GeoJson file containing Multipolygons to split up the country into postcodes.

My map is set up in the following way:

```
<div id="printableMap"></div>
var map = L.map('printableMap', {
        'center': [55.483959, -2.244644],
        'zoom': 6,
        'maxBounds': maxBounds
    });
L.tileLayer('LINK TO MAPQUEST', {
        type: 'map',
        ext: 'jpg',
        attribution: 'LINK TO MAPQUEST',
        subdomains: '1234',
        minZoom: 6,
        maxZoom: 9
    }).addTo(map);

var geoJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    L.geoJson(geoJson, {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        style: function (feature) {
            if ($.inArray(feature.properties.Name, postcodes.split(',')) > -1) {
                return {
                    color: "#000000",
                    weight: 2.5,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                    fillColor: "#0000ff"
                };
            } else {
                return getDefaultStyle();
            }
        }
    }).addTo(map);

map.on('zoomend', function () {
    map.invalidateSize();
});
map.on('dragend', function () {
    map.invalidateSize();
});
```

My issue arrises when printing the map through the browser print option, after I have manipulated the map (zooming, panning) - it seems like the geojson layer is not updating to match the map, and is also overflowing the div containing the map.

[Screenshot of a print preview of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERBfz.png)

I was under the impression that the map.invalidateSize should update the geoJson layer to fit the map, am I missing something?

Edit - I am getting the expected print out when using IE8, Chrome and Firefox, but not IE Edge.

Edit - I've tried recreating the map in the same way as it is created before the print command is sent, but this then prints the geoJson layer scaled up to fill the page and none of the map tiles.